# Is there a "the" definition of a lattice?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, terminology, definition, crystallography

I'm writing a paper about lattices in the complex plane, and while trying to explain the crystallographic restriction theorem, I realized that I never actually defined what a 'lattice' *is*. The ostensive definition which I have effectively been using is that a lattice [in the complex plane]

1. is a [countable] set $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{C}$
2. forms a finitely generated Abelian group under addition

However, these criteria do not exlude structures which are not usually thought of as 'lattices'. For example, certain quasicrystals and aperiodic tilings may satisfy these criteria (thus I cannot safely say that a 'lattice' may only have 2,3,4, or 6-fold rotational symmetry).

But when I look back through my references, I can't find anything to suggest that these objects are *not* examples of lattices - albeit not the usual ones.

The distinction is easy enough to make and somewhat novel - I could easily replace 'lattice' in places with 'periodic lattice' to make the problem go away.

In any case, is there a "the" definition of a lattice I should be using which makes this distinction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice#In_2_dimensions

Comment: *"a set $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{C}$ (which is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$)"* is senseless to me.

Comment: @YCor Why is it senseless?

Comment: "isomorphic" refers to some kind of structure. isomorphic as subset, would mean have the same cardinal, and hence, here "isomorphic to a subset of $R^2$" would be a tortuous way to say "of at most continuum cardinal", which here is an empty assumption. So it's probably not what you mean, and I have no idea what you mean, and it's even not clear if you mean "$\Lambda$, which is" or "$\mathbf{C}$, which is"; in both case the sentence is awkward. Maybe, you just mean that you identify $\mathbf{C}$ with $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Comment: @YCor Okay, I see what you mean. "isomorphic" was in reference to $\mathbf{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{C}$ as vector spaces because two-dimensional lattices are commonly described using vectors in $\mathbf{R}^2$. It made a lot more sense in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lattice is a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is of rank $n$ (i.e. it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ under addition).

Comment: In your case, you want a rank 2 subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Would a lattice then be any countable subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ endowed with a discrete topology?

Comment: Addendum to the previous - defined for a given topology $\tau_r$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ [s.t. if $\tau_\lambda$ is the discrete topology on $\Lambda$ (the lattice/subgroup), then $\tau_\lambda\subseteq\tau_r$]?

Comment: It should be discrete under the induced topology.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a go-to source for this definition? It's fine if there isn't, but it would be nice to have something on hand to cite.

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Comment: An alternate--but equivalent--definition is a rank $n$ subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.